# How to use logical conditions in XML?

Tags: c, xml, xml-parsing, logical-operators, yang

```
<install-condition header-file="platform/lib_platform.h">is_bcm_soc_brd1() || is_bcm_soc_brd2() || is_bcm_soc_brd3()</install-condition>
```

Here my input board type is is_board_jkl, so the function is_bcm_soc_brd3() will return True.
The problem is is_bcm_soc_brd3() and is_bcm_soc_brd4 have a common item.

But my requirement is that, if the board is is_board_jkl, dont execute further.
i.e. in C code I can written this as follows,

```
If ( is_bcm_soc_brd1() || is_bcm_soc_brd2() ||   (is_bcm_soc_brd3() && !is_bcm_soc_brd4())
 {
    //do the action
 }
```

How to write the equivalent code in the below given XML tag?

```
 <install-condition header-file="platform/lib_platform.h">is_bcm_soc_brd1() || is_bcm_soc_brd2() || is_bcm_soc_brd3()</install-condition>
```

**cat platform/lib_platform.h**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_bcm_soc_brd1()
{
  if (is_board_abc())
    return TRUE;

  return FALSE;
}

int is_bcm_soc_brd2()
{
  if (is_board_def())
    return TRUE;

  return FALSE;
}


int is_bcm_soc_brd3()
{
  if (is_board_ghi() || (is_board_jkl()))  
    return TRUE;

  return FALSE;
}

int is_bcm_soc_brd4()
{
  if (is_board_jkl())
    return TRUE;

  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write following in XML:

(name is 'ABC' AND (language is NOT english) AND (country is Belgium OR Germany OR France OR Italy)) as:

['|','|','|',('country_id.code','=','be'),('country_id.code','=','ge'),('country_id.code','=','fr'),('country_id.code','=','it'),('name','=','ABC'),('language.code','!=','en_US'),]

Country code maybe different you can replace country code with correct one in above sentense.

Thanks

Comment: Consider editing your answer and make it more readable, I would like to propose an edit but the queue was full.

Comment: done Ozgur Bagci